# 'Series' object is not callable error when converting pandas dataframe to string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file that contains tripadvisor reviews:

[image]

r_text column:

```
r_text

Beautiful architecture . A magnificent
Amazing. This is a place that takes your breath away!"Absolutely something to see and experience during a life."""
Church and Mosque together. This may be the only place where you find within a building 02 structural design of different worship in one single building.
Magical setting . The name Hagia Sofia is enchanting just like the place both inside and outside and especially at sunset and night time. The history and architecture is stunning.
Majestic although its shear simplicity. A monument worth visiting. A huge dedication to religious faith having its origins back in the 6th century! You don't have to be an architect or a civil engineer to appreciate the immaculate structural integrity of this massive structure. Centuries of history from two different cultures
```

I am using Pandas for reading the CSV, and I would like to convert all text to string from the r_text column. Here's my code:

```
activity = pd.read_csv(...\reviews_activities_cleaned.csv')
review = activity.r_text
allreviews = str(review)
```

but, I got this 'Series' error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Anyone have an idea to solve this error? Thank you, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you put a link to that csv file or write a part of it in raw format (not a picture) in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
allreviews = list(review)
```

or

```
allreviews = review.agg('sum')
```

depending if you want a list of texts, or a single string with all the texts.